# Find consecutive integers in a list

Tags: python, list, integer

I am trying to find consecutive values from an unsorted list. Experimental code below:

```
num = [8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 3]

#(num[0+1])  next value

for i in range(len(num)-1):  # not using -1 will cause index error
    if num[i]+1==num[i+1]:
        print('Con',num[i])
```

Problem: I am unable to get the last value with this current code. My output excludes the last value. Here is what I get (no 9 or no 3):

```
Con 8
Con 1
Con 2
```

I have seen a few complex solutions which were a little difficult for me to understand. Is it possible to tweak the for loop part a little and get the entire sequence? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want only **pairs** of consecutive numbers, or `n` consecutive numbers?

Comment: 8,9 and 1,2,3. Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you only check the *next* number. When you want the second number (like 9 or 3), you have to include a check for the *previous* number too. This will make the `if` a bit longer, but it'll work.

```
num=[8,9,4,1,2,3]

for i in range(len(num)):
    if (
        (  # check for the next number
            i + 1 != len (num) and  # don't check the end of the list
            num[i]+1==num[i+1] 
        ) or (  # check for the previous number
            i != 0 and  # don't check before the list
            num [i-1] == num [i] - 1
        )
    ): print('Con',num[i])
```

Also, I had to remove the `-1` in your range, because I already do a manual check, and as pointed out, this prvented 3 from being shown.

Comment: The output is 8, 9, 1, 2. I think OP wants 3 to be included.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that (I checked for being the last element twice)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

num = [8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 3]

# Enumerate and get differences between counter—integer pairs
# Group by differences (consecutive integers have equal differences)  
gb = groupby(enumerate(num), key=lambda x: x[0] - x[1])

# Repack elements from each group into list
all_groups = ([i[1] for i in g] for _, g in gb)

# Filter out one element lists
list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, all_groups))
# [[8, 9], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Wow, great! Could you explain how it works? It could be very useful for beginners

Comment: @Konrad I added some comments.

Comment: Thanks! Still, I would love to hear more details about `all_groups` line. As far as I understand, `gb` creates a `dict`-like object using `groupby`. So, in `all_groups`,  `_` stores grouped differences between a value and its position (index) in the list, while `g` contains tuples describing `(index, value)` pairs. `i[1]` in a nested list comprehension extracts only values. Am I right?

Comment: @Konrad Exactly!

Comment: Okay. So 2 final questions. Why `gb` always has to be refreshed before other operations? When I converted `gb` for debugging purposes to a list - it became empty when running `all_groups`. Second of all - what's the purpose of `_`? I mean underlines have its special meaning in Python but I don't get it.

Comment: all_groups is a generator (read about generators in Python). `_` is used in Python by convention as a placeholder variable (I don't use this variable later).

Answer (score 1):

Your code only tests in one direction (being followed by a consecutive number).
For the full sequence you have to test in both direction.

```
num=[8,9,4,1,2,3]

assert(len(num) > 1)
for i, n in enumerate(num):
    if i != 0:
        if n == num[i-1] + 1:
            print("Con", n)
            continue
    if i != len(num) - 1:
        if n == num[i+1] - 1:
            print("Con", n)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to print both numbers when you found them to be consecutive, but also check that the one at index `i-1` was not in the consecutive list as well so that the number at index `i` is not printed twice:

```
num = [8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 3]

for i in range(len(num)-1):  # not using -1 will cause index error
    if num[i] + 1 == num[i + 1]:
        if i == 0 or (i - 1 >= 0 and num[i - 1] != num[i] - 1):
            print('Con', num[i])
        print('Con', num[i + 1])
```

Could try with a more complex list as well:

```
num = [8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 6, 1]

for i in range(len(num)-1):  # not using -1 will cause index error
    if num[i] + 1 == num[i + 1]:
        if i == 0 or (i - 1 >= 0 and num[i - 1] != num[i] - 1):
            print('Con', num[i])
        print('Con', num[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = [8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 3]

def con(rng, pos=0):
    if pos < len(rng):
        if (pos > 0 and rng[pos]-1 == rng[pos-1]) or (pos < len(rng) -1 and rng[pos]+1 == rng[pos+1]):
            print("con", rng[pos])
        con(rng, pos+1)

con(num)
```

edit:
this is solution is based on concurrent function, and needs only the list as argument. As long as they are within lower-/upperbound of list, the function will check if (previous number)-1 or (next number)+1 are equal (this number)
output will be:
con 8
con 9
con 1
con 2
con 3

Comment: While this code may answer the posted question, it's best to include a short description of how the code works and why you've made the choices you have, if possible. At the least, a sample of inputs and their respective outputs would improve this answer.